# DataGridView's cell transparency in BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, transparency, background-color

I need transparency in DataGridView's cells (ie. `grid1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20,120,120,120);`). I know I need to create a new control and inherit the DataGridView and make the background of the control to parent's color so I will be able to use transparency in cells.

This has been covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462381/1181261) answer:

```
protected override void PaintBackground(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,  Rectangle gridBounds)
  {
    base.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds);
    Rectangle rectSource = new Rectangle(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
    Rectangle rectDest = new Rectangle(0, 0, rectSource.Width, rectSource.Height);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Parent.ClientRectangle.Width, Parent.ClientRectangle.Height);
    Graphics.FromImage(b).DrawImage(this.Parent.BackgroundImage, Parent.ClientRectangle);


    graphics.DrawImage(b, rectDest, rectSource, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // I would like to set background the same as parent's background here
  }
```

However, this works only if parent has background image. Author of the answer also said

> [...] just ask if the parent have background image, **else just use
> the parent backcolor to paint your grid, and that is all**.

So how to use the parent's background color?

Comment: winforms doesn't (seriously) support transparency. Your options are: 1 - get rid of dinosaur winforms and use WPF. 2 - leave winforms to the default ugly non-customizable Windows 3.1 like stuff, never trying to customize anything. 3 - put an `ElementHost` and use WPF while keeping other winforms stuff.

Comment: I've just tried it and looks like the CellPainting does not support color with **alpha** not being 255. That means you can only implement some **totally** transparency. Although as HighCore said, it's not true transparency, it's just some kind of mimicking, we just need to paint all the behind parts on the top canvas (the cell) and it will look like totally transparent. If a solution for totally transparent cells is acceptable to you, just leave some comment back and I'll give the answer. It's so simple that we don't need any custom painting.

Comment: @HighCore, I've already impelmented huge portion of the application in winforms. I will look into WPF after this project though, I promise (to myself)! King King, I need medium transparency too.