# How to C# WinForm DataGridView Background Color Transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, background, transparent

**Similar Thread**
[Set datagrid view background to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330220/set-datagrid-view-background-to-transparent)

**DataGridView VB Transparent Code:**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class TransparentDGV
    Inherits DataGridView

    Private _DGVHasTransparentBackground As Boolean

    <Category("Transparency"), Description("Select whether the control has a Transparent Background.")> Public Property DGVHasTransparentBackground As Boolean
        Get
            Return _DGVHasTransparentBackground
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _DGVHasTransparentBackground = value
            If _DGVHasTransparentBackground Then
                SetTransparentProperties(True)
            Else
                SetTransparentProperties(False)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        DGVHasTransparentBackground = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetTransparentProperties(ByRef SetAsTransparent As Boolean)
        If SetAsTransparent Then
            MyBase.DoubleBuffered = True
            MyBase.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
            MyBase.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            MyBase.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent)
        Else
            MyBase.DoubleBuffered = False
            MyBase.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = True
            MyBase.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
            MyBase.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
            SetCellStyle(Color.White)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub PaintBackground(ByVal graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics, ByVal clipBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle, ByVal gridBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle)
        MyBase.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds)

        If _DGVHasTransparentBackground Then
            If Not IsNothing(MyBase.Parent.BackgroundImage) Then
                Dim rectSource As New Rectangle(MyBase.Location, MyBase.Size)
                Dim rectDest As New Rectangle(0, 0, rectSource.Width, rectSource.Height)

                Dim b As New Bitmap(Parent.ClientRectangle.Width, Parent.ClientRectangle.Height)
                graphics.FromImage(b).DrawImage(MyBase.Parent.BackgroundImage, Parent.ClientRectangle)
                graphics.DrawImage(b, rectDest, rectSource, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Else
                Dim myBrush As New SolidBrush(MyBase.Parent.BackColor)
                Dim rectDest As New Region(New Rectangle(0, 0, MyBase.Width, MyBase.Height))
                graphics.FillRegion(myBrush, rectDest)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnColumnAdded(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnColumnAdded(e)
        If _DGVHasTransparentBackground Then
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetCellStyle(ByVal cellColour As Color)
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In MyBase.Columns
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = cellColour
            col.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = cellColour
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Convert C# Code ?
Help !!

OR**

```
protected override void PaintBackground(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,  Rectangle gridBounds)   {
    base.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds);
    Rectangle rectSource = new Rectangle(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
    Rectangle rectDest = new Rectangle(0, 0, rectSource.Width, rectSource.Height);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Parent.ClientRectangle.Width, Parent.ClientRectangle.Height);
    Graphics.FromImage(b).DrawImage(this.Parent.BackgroundImage, Parent.ClientRectangle);


    graphics.DrawImage(b, rectDest, rectSource, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    SetCellsTransparent();   }


public void SetCellsTransparent() {
    this.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
    this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    this.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;


    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.Columns)
    {
        col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        col.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
    } }
```

**Example Project Please or code**
**I cannot run this code.**

Comment: use code converter like this one for example: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have already thought of it. - Srriam Sakthivel
I wanted to project.
Nonetheless Thanks. :)

Project download : https://www.mediafire.com/?1nac18vdpdg27x5
Example image:
http://s1278.photobucket.com/user/murat34can52/media/datagridviewTransparent_zpstgnkjsb7.png.html

**Source Code

Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winFormDataGridViewTransparentAndImage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /*
            VB olan bu kodu C# internetteki convert siteleri sayesinde çevirdim
            Ancak yeterli olmadı hata alıyordu nedeni bunu Form1.Designer.cs den
            itibaren başlayan bir class olayı olduğu için. Nesne oluşturulurken
            bizim verdiğimiz özelliklere göre oluşturulması gerekiyordu.
            Neyse uzatmadan baya zaman harcadım C# çevirmek ve doğru istenilen
            amaca ulaşmak için ama sonunda başarmak önemli adımlarımdan biri oldu.

            #Murat Çakmak (Dikey)         
         */

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Columns1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Columns2");

            dt.Rows.Add("Rows1", "Rows1");
            dt.Rows.Add("Rows2", "Rows2");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(0,0);
            dataGridView2.Size = new Size(0,0);
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(350, 350);
            dataGridView2.Size = new Size(350, 350);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1 Designer**

```
namespace winFormDataGridViewTransparentAndImage
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dataGridView2 = new transDataGridView();
            this.dataGridView1 = new transDataGridViewAndImage();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 397);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button1.Text = "Size++";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // dataGridView2
            // 
            this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView2.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
            this.dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
            this.dataGridView2.DGVHasTransparentBackground = true;
            this.dataGridView2.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(369, 12);
            this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
            this.dataGridView2.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView2.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
            this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(337, 206);
            this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.DGVHasTransparentBackground = true;
            this.dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle5;
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle6;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(304, 206);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(782, 432);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private transDataGridViewAndImage dataGridView1;
        private transDataGridView dataGridView2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;


    }
}
```

**Transparent DataGridView Class Source**

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class transDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    // VB Converted To C# And Code Edit : Murat Çakmak
    private bool _DGVHasTransparentBackground;
    [Category("Transparency"), Description("Select whether the control has a Transparent Background.")]
    public bool DGVHasTransparentBackground
    {
        get { return _DGVHasTransparentBackground; }
        set
        {
            _DGVHasTransparentBackground = value;
            if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
            {
                this.SetTransparentProperties(true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.SetTransparentProperties(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public transDataGridView()
    {
        DGVHasTransparentBackground = true;
    }

    private void SetTransparentProperties(bool SetAsTransparent)
    {
        if (SetAsTransparent)
        {
            base.DoubleBuffered = true;
            base.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            base.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            base.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent);
        }
        else
        {
            base.DoubleBuffered = false;
            base.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true;
            base.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            base.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            SetCellStyle(Color.White);
        }
    }

    protected override void PaintBackground(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle gridBounds)
    {
        base.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds);

        if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
        {
            //  DataGridView Transparent !
            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(base.Parent.BackColor); // (Form1 BackColor) veya bir resme boyanabilir.
            Region rectDest = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, base.Width, base.Height));
            graphics.FillRegion(myBrush, rectDest);


        }
    }

    protected override void OnColumnAdded(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
        if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
        {
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent);
        }
    }

    private void SetCellStyle(Color cellColour)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in base.Columns)
        {
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = cellColour;
            col.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = cellColour; // selection cell color example Color.Red;
        }
    }

}
```

**Transparent DataGridView And İmage Class Source**

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class transDataGridViewAndImage : DataGridView
{
    // VB Converted To C# And Code Edit : Murat Çakmak
    private bool _DGVHasTransparentBackground;
    [Category("Transparency"), Description("Select whether the control has a Transparent Background.")]
    public bool DGVHasTransparentBackground
    {
        get { return _DGVHasTransparentBackground; }
        set
        {
            _DGVHasTransparentBackground = value;
            if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
            {
                this.SetTransparentProperties(true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.SetTransparentProperties(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public transDataGridViewAndImage()
    {
        DGVHasTransparentBackground = true;
    }

    private void SetTransparentProperties(bool SetAsTransparent)
    {
        if (SetAsTransparent)
        {
            base.DoubleBuffered = true;
            base.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            base.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            base.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent);
        }
        else
        {
            base.DoubleBuffered = false;
            base.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true;
            base.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            base.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            SetCellStyle(Color.White);
        }
    }

    bool imageLoad = false;

    protected override void PaintBackground(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle gridBounds)
    {
        base.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds);

        if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
        {
            //  DataGridView İmage Load !
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(winFormDataGridViewTransparentAndImage.Properties.Resources._3d_Hd_Wallpapers);
            graphics.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, base.Size.Width, base.Size.Height);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnColumnAdded(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnColumnAdded(e);
        if (_DGVHasTransparentBackground)
        {
            SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent);
        }
    }

    private void SetCellStyle(Color cellColour)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in base.Columns)
        {
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = cellColour;
            col.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = cellColour;
        }
    }

}
```