# VB.NET - Hide the top left corner cell of a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, header, hide, visible

I have a datagridview with 3 rows and 2 columns. My rows and columns have headers.

The problem is that i have an empty cell on the top left corner of my datagridview. I think it is the column header of my rowheaders or something like that. I don't success to hide this cell, is it possible ?

Thank you

**Example :**

```
hide this cell  | colHead1| colHead2 |
--------------------------------------
firstname       | x       | y        |
lastname        | x1      | y1       |
society         | x2      | y2       |
```

**EDIT :**
I tried to set the property `dtgv.TopLeftHeaderCell.Visible` to False, but it is ReadOnly.

Comment: You can set `DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False` but I don't think you can accomplish what you want.  You're asking to hide a cell that must exist if both column headers and row headers are shown, otherwise it would show what - grey background?

Comment: @OhBeWise yes, i would like to show the background of the form. If i set the Visible property to False, it will hide my headers and i want to keep them.

Comment: @OhBeWise Oh sorry, i forgot to try your solution since i was in holidays. It works very well, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rescind my comment. You *can* accomplish this - manually. For example, in your `DataGridView.CellPainting` event handler in a bland/unmodified `DataGridView`, you can match the background like so:

```
If e.RowIndex < 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then
    Using brush As New SolidBrush(Me.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds)
    End Using

    e.Handled = True
End If
```

[image]

---

> i would like to show the background of the form

If you meant you want to set the `DataGridView` background to the Form's background these two (C#) answers by users [Deumber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462381/3773066) and [letsdance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903052/3773066) demonstrate the general setup to crop the correct portion of the Form's image into the `DataGridView`. Using their methods (without calling `SetCellsTransparent()`) coupled with the following change to your `DataGridView.CellPainting` event handler should work:

```
If e.RowIndex < 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, e.CellBounds)  
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

[image]