# Set alpha from datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is it possible to set the alpha property of a datagridview in C#?

I've tried:

```
dgvPlaylist.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Gray);
```

I have a picturebox on the back of the datagridview. But when I add this code the background of the dataGridView is white.

```
dgvPlaylist.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the opacity of a datagridview row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914484/how-to-set-the-opacity-of-a-datagridview-row)

Comment: I find the dup-target *link-only* answer unsatisfactory.  Shameless plug: check out my [answer to "Hide the top left corner cell of a datagridview"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288319/3773066) which actually applies to the entire DGV.  It's in VB but the conversion should be simple.

Comment: A winforms DGV is not meant to support this. Making the Cells semi-transparent will only let the DGV Backcolor shine through. Instead you would have to code the CellPainting event to draw the correct part of the image in the picturebox. Possible but quite some work. You need to consider the placement and viewmode and also take care of users shuffling columns and resizing rows and columns..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a hex color instead of Argb.

```
dgvPlaylist.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#AA999999"));
dgvPlaylist.Parent = pictureBox1;
```