# How to make a fixed background on a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I made a custom control that inherits `DataGridView` in order to have a transparent background. Now I am trying to set up an scroll feature on a timer that scrolls down one row every second. However, when I try to scroll (vertically), the background image is not fixed. Is there any way to make the background image fixed when scrolling?

EDIT: Here is the code for handling the scroll timer.

```
Private Sub Sub1

    'Some previous code

    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 10 Then
        ScrollIndex1 = 0 'Integer for scroll index
        DGVAutoScroll()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DGVAutoScroll()

    Timer2.Enabled = True
    Timer2.Interval = 1000

End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    If ScrollIndex1 = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        ScrollIndex1 = 0
        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = ScrollIndex1
        ScrollIndex1 += 1
    Else
        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = ScrollIndex1
        ScrollIndex1 += 1
    End If

End Sub

'Custom DataGridView class
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MyDGV
    Inherits DataGridView

    Public Property DGVHasTransparentBackground As Boolean
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set()
            SetTransparentProperties(True)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ScrollBar
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value)
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        DGVHasTransparentBackground = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetTransparentProperties(ByRef SetAsTransparent As Boolean)
        MyBase.DoubleBuffered = True
        MyBase.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
        MyBase.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        MyBase.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent)
    End Sub


    Protected Overrides Sub PaintBackground(graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics, clipBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle, gridBounds As System.Drawing.Rectangle)
        MyBase.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds)

        Dim rectSource As New Rectangle(MyBase.Location, MyBase.Size)
        Dim rectDest As New Rectangle(0, 0, rectSource.Width, rectSource.Height)

        Dim b As New Bitmap(Parent.ClientRectangle.Width, Parent.ClientRectangle.Height)
        Graphics.FromImage(b).DrawImage(MyBase.Parent.BackgroundImage, Parent.ClientRectangle)
        graphics.DrawImage(b, rectDest, rectSource, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnColumnAdded(e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnColumnAdded(e)

        SetCellStyle(Color.Transparent)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetCellStyle(ByVal cellColour As Color)
        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In MyBase.Columns
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = cellColour
            col.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = cellColour
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please provide us the code of what have you done let see what causes the problem.

Comment: What you mean by `background is not fixed`?

Comment: Check [letsdance's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33903052/3773066) answer here to the question "*Set datagrid view background to transparent*". Particularly the override of `CreateParams`. It's in C#, so if that's a problem, the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) usually does a good job helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I had to call DataGridView1.SelectAll() within the timer tick. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an image behind data (*datagridview*).

If *datagridview* is transparent then just **add an image in the background**. Stick it on the form or on an item behind *datagridview*. It will no scroll since it would be outside *datagridview*

Change image alpha if data not clearly visible.